# How to correctly indent original mails with ActionMailer/Mailgun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mailgun

I'm currently receiving emails with Mailgun API and I'd like to automatically respond to any received email.

I've already defined the header params In-Reply-To and References in the autorespond emails and that kinda does the job, but I'd also like to indent/quote original text below my reply for other mail clients (like Mail.app on the iPhone) which don't stack emails correctly.

Any suggestions/tips on how I can accomplish that?

Thanks.